# Plot Networkx graph on a real world map

Tags: python, networkx

I have a vehicle routing (VRP) model output currently visulized using networkx. In addition, I want to further add the networkx graph on a real world map (see below). Is there anyot useful map tools that works with Networkx Graph? Or, any packages that help to draw such visulization directly on a real world map?

Below is the networx part of the code and the graph.

```
def DrawNetwork():
    G = nx.DiGraph()
    locations = DataProblem()._locations
    # print(locations)
    x = 0
    for vehicle_id in vlist:
        n = 0
        e = []
        node = []
        cl=PickupColor(x)

        for i in vehicle_id:
            G.add_node(i, pos=(locations[i][0], locations[i][1]))
            if n > 0:
                u = (vehicle_id[n - 1], vehicle_id[n])
                e.append(u)
                node.append(i)
                G.add_edge(vehicle_id[n - 1], vehicle_id[n])
                nx.draw(G, nx.get_node_attributes(G, 'pos'), nodelist=node, edgelist=e, with_labels=True,
                        node_color=cl, width=2, edge_color=cl,
                        style='dashed', font_color='w', font_size=12, font_family='sans-serif')
            n += 1
        x += 1
    # let's color the node 0 in black
    nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, locations, nodelist=[0], node_color='k')
    plt.axis('on')
    # plt.show()
```

current visulization using Networkx

[image]

The future visualization I desire:

[image]

Comment: I think you are looking for [osmnx](https://github.com/gboeing/osmnx).