# Plotly: How to plot arrow line (directed graph)?

Tags: plotly, mapbox

I want to plot an arrow line between nodes to indicate the direction of routes. I cannot find such a built-in function to do so. Is there a method to do this work?

my codes:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import plotly.io as pio
import plotly

lon1 = [113.076843, 113.154191, 113.737213, 113.842405, 114.244183 ]
lat1 = [23.10993, 23.218533, 23.047626, 22.987975, 22.601581 ]

lon2 = [113.364738, 113.664108, 113.661705,114.244183]
lat2 = [22.997112, 22.878038, 22.869216, 22.601581]

lon_trip1 = lon1
lat_trip1 = lat1

lon_trip2 = lon2
lat_trip2 = lat2

fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_trace(go.Scattermapbox(
    mode="markers+lines",
    lon=lon_trip1,
    lat=lat_trip1,
    name="trip1", marker={'size': 10}))

fig.add_trace(
    go.Scattermapbox(
        mode="markers+lines",
        lon=lon_trip2,
        lat=lat_trip2,
        name="trip2",
        marker={'size': 10}))

fig.update_layout(
    margin={'l': 113, 't': 24, 'b': 22, 'r': 115},
    mapbox=dict(style='carto-positron',
                center=go.layout.mapbox.Center(lon=113.664, lat=22.878),
                pitch=0,
                zoom=8)
)


pio.write_image(fig,'C:/Users/Jie/Desktop/plot.png',width=1980, height=1080)
#plotly.offline.plot(fig, filename='C:/Users/user/Desktop/plot' + '.html')
fig.show()
```

In addition, I want to further add the networkx graph on a real world map. it it possible to use plotly to add the map layer to the original networkx graph?

the full code are here:
[Plot Networkx graph on a real world map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64039030/plot-networkx-graph-on-a-real-world-map)

Answer (score 2):

- you can add **geojson** layers to **mapbox** figures
- this approach creates a marker at middle of each line segment to show direction of travel
- the marker is rotated using high school trigonometry to work out angle of travel
- have extended solution based on comments.  Can now request placement using `place` parameter.  Image shows **beyond** options include **centre, end, beyond**

[image]

#### code

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.io as pio
import plotly
import math
import shapely.geometry
from shapely.affinity import rotate as R, translate as T

lon1 = [113.076843, 113.154191, 113.737213, 113.842405, 114.244183]
lat1 = [23.10993, 23.218533, 23.047626, 22.987975, 22.601581]

lon2 = [113.364738, 113.664108, 113.661705, 114.244183]
lat2 = [22.997112, 22.878038, 22.869216, 22.601581]

lon_trip1 = lon1
lat_trip1 = lat1

lon_trip2 = lon2
lat_trip2 = lat2

fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_trace(
    go.Scattermapbox(
        mode="markers+lines",
        lon=lon_trip1,
        lat=lat_trip1,
        name="trip1",
        marker={"size": 10},
    )
)

fig.add_trace(
    go.Scattermapbox(
        mode="markers+lines",
        lon=lon_trip2,
        lat=lat_trip2,
        name="trip2",
        marker={"size": 10},
    )
)

# create a mapbox layer that are arrows that show direction between sequence of lat / lon pairs
def direction(lat1, lon1, marker=None, color="yellow", place="center"):
    # default marker is a left pointing arrow, centred as 0,0
    # it may be necessary to adjust sizing
    if marker is None:
        m = R(shapely.geometry.Polygon([(0, 0), (0, 1), (0.5, 0.5)]), 0)
        m = shapely.affinity.scale(m, xfact=0.05, yfact=0.05)  # size appropriately
        m = T(m, -m.centroid.x, -m.centroid.y)
    else:
        m = marker

    def place_marker(m, x1, x0, y1, y0, place=place):
        theta = math.atan2(x1 - x0, y1 - y0)
        if place == "center":
            p = dict(
                xoff=(y1 - y0) / 2 + y0,
                yoff=(x1 - x0) / 2 + x0,
            )
        elif place == "end":
            p = dict(xoff=y1, yoff=x1)
        elif place == "beyond":
            H = .05
            p = dict(xoff=y1 + math.cos(theta)*H, yoff=x1 + math.sin(theta)*H)
        return T(R(m, theta, use_radians=True), **p)

    return {
        # list of geometries rotated based on direction and centred on line between pairs of points
        "source": shapely.geometry.MultiPolygon(
            [
                place_marker(m, x1, x0, y1, y0)
                for x0, x1, y0, y1 in zip(lat1, lat1[1:], lon1, lon1[1:])
            ]
        ).__geo_interface__,
        "type": "fill",
        "color": color,
        "below":"traces"
    }


fig.update_layout(
    margin={"l": 113, "t": 24, "b": 22, "r": 115},
    mapbox=dict(
        style="carto-positron",
        center=go.layout.mapbox.Center(lon=113.664, lat=22.878),
        pitch=0,
        zoom=8,
        layers=[
            direction(t.lat, t.lon, marker=None, color=c, place="beyond")
            for t, c in zip(fig.data, px.colors.qualitative.Plotly)
        ],
    ),
)
```

Comment: thank you for your help. is it possible to position the arrow at the end of the line not in the middle, just like a normal arrow line?

Comment: yep - updated to provide this flexibility as well.

Comment: for some reason, my machine could not install geopandas. I just found this direct drawing method: https://community.plotly.com/t/plotly-arrow-in-scattergeo-with-text-on-the-line/34060 I am not sure if it works.

Comment: https://plotly.com/python/map-configuration/ mapbox and geo are quite different to work with...  has shapely installed on your machine? I have removed dependency on geopandas

Comment: Dear Rob thanks so much. this is way much better. how to adjust the arrow to make it not overlapped with the node i.e. (shift the arrow in front of the node not on it)? I have number shown on the node which will be covered if they wereto be overlapped.

Comment: updated again - just more coding and use of trigonometry that is taught to 13 year olds.  I remember "silly old harry caught a hearing trawling over the Atlantic" for sin/cos/tan ...

Comment: Rob is it possible to set the arrow size dynamically based on the distance between the source and destination points? Currently for locations continents apart the arrow spans across multiple cities or states and if we reduce the scale it is then hard to see the arrow for the longer distances.